# OroPlatform without any entity alias

Tags: orocommerce

My OroPlatform-based system has no registered alias.

When I enter the command ***php bin/console oro:entity-alias:debug*** in the terminal, it returns only the result below:

```
Class Alias Plural Alias
```

Does anyone have any idea what may have made all entity alias disappear?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when you have an inconsistent cache.

Please, clear the cache with `rm -rf var/cache/*` and run `php bin/console oro:platform:update` command to warm all the caches up and synchronize the application code with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for your help.

Yeah, I figured that would be it. I've done this before, but to no avail. I'm going back to the commits.

But I still have no idea what is going on. I will check for any inconsistencies in the DB.